# JTextField not visible in invoked method

Tags: java, jtextfield

I'm trying to populate a Panel with a textfield and a label, the label is being reflecting as expected, however the textfield is not showing up.
Below is the code that is being used:

```
    package qmutility;

    import java.awt.GridLayout;     
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class panetest1 
    {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            createSubframe();

        }

        public static void createSubframe()
        {
            final JFrame subframe = new JFrame("Object Choice");
            subframe.setSize(1000, 500);        
            subframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            subframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            JTextArea out = new JTextArea();
            out.setEditable (false);
            JScrollPane jp = new  JScrollPane(out);
            jp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            jp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

            JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

            JPanel queue = new JPanel();
            JLabel lblqname = new JLabel("Please enter the queue name");
            JTextField txtqname = new JTextField(20);

            queue.add(lblqname, txtqname);

            JPanel chl = new JPanel();

            tabbedPane.addTab("Queues", queue);
            tabbedPane.addTab("Channels", chl);     
            subframe.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
            subframe.getContentPane().add(jp);
            tabbedPane.setVisible(true);
            subframe.setVisible(true);      
        }

    }
```

Edit: Attached the screengrab[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwOG1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the Layout of your panel.

Like, `queue.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

or Add components to panel one by one,

```
queue.add(lblqname);
queue.add(txtqname);
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick one, I did try it upon your recommendation, outcome remains unchanged.

Comment: thanks a ton @grathour & Berger....
That did the trick...

Much obliged

Comment: sorry for misspelling your name, damned P on keyboard gives me the jitters...

while trying to accept your answer it says, you can accept the answer in a minute... Guess I should be waiting for that window

Comment: @flunkedutopian No worries about the name. :) Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The method [Container.add(Component comp,Object constraints)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) adds a given `Component` with given **constraints**, it is not meant to add two `Component` at once.

Replace :

```
queue.add(lblqname, txtqname);
```

With

```
queue.add(lblqname);
queue.add(txtqname);
```